# Why chrome.sync.set updates a value only once

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want the extension to count how many times the browser was opened.
Below is the piece of code which should do the job, but does not work as
expected. **Why?**

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {  
    chrome.storage.sync.get({'number' : 1}, function(result) {
        // prints 1 the first time, then keeps printing 2 all the time, why?
        console.log("Old number is " + result.number);

        // Trying to increment 'number' value by 1
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'number' : (result.number + 1)},
            function() {})
    });
});
```

Comment: AFAIK it should work as is. There's probably some problem with syncing in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you should be using "1" in `get`...

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {  
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['number'], function(result) {
        let number;
        if ('number' in result)
            number = result.number;
        else
            number = 1;

        // prints 1 the first time, then keeps printing 2 all the time, why?
        console.log("Old number is " + number);

        number += 1;

        // Trying to increment 'number' value by 1
        chrome.storage.sync.set({number: number},
            function() {console.log("value as set to " + number);});
    });
});
```

This code should probably be on a "background script", and the only console that will show anything is the console you open from "tools, more tools, extensions" and click the view link in your listed extension.

If you're having problems with syncing as mentioned in comments, you can try using `chrome.storage.local.get / set`.

I think that for what you're doing, this is better.